# How to call a variable from main.go file to an html file?

Tags: html, go

In this code, I have an about function in `main.go` in which I am trying to get the `Content` variable data in `about.html`. I called `{{.Content}}` in `about.html` but it shows no result when I fill the textarea. How to handle this?

**about.html**

```
{{template "base" .}}
{{define "title"}} About {{end}}
{{define "body"}}
    {{if .Success}}
        {{.Content}}
    {{else}}
        <h1>About</h1>
        <form action="/about" method="POST" name="about" id="about">
            <div>
                <label>Content</label>
                <textarea name="content"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </div>
        </form>
    {{end}}
{{end}}
```

**main.go**

```
func makeTemlate(base string) *template.Template {
    files := []string{base, "ui/html/footer.html", "ui/html/base.html"}
    return template.Must(template.ParseFiles(files...))
}

var aboutTmpl  = makeTemlate("ui/html/about.html")

type Details struct {
    Content string
}

func about(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.Method != http.MethodPost {
        aboutTmpl.Execute(w, nil)
        return
    }
    details := Details{
        Content: r.FormValue("content"),
    }
    _ = details
    aboutTmpl.Execute(w, struct{ Success bool }{true})
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/about", about)
    log.Println("Starting the server at :4000")
    http.ListenAndServe(":4000", nil)
}
```

Comment: you have to execute the template with aforementionned argument. At `aboutTmpl.Execute(w, struct{ Success bool }{true})` You are passing a struct as argument, it only exposes one field, `Success`. You might want to write somthing like `aboutTmpl.Execute(w, struct{ Success bool ; Content string }{Success:true, Content: r.FormValue("Content")})`

Comment: @mh-cbon It still didn't show the result.

Comment: how about writing a test ? https://blog.questionable.services/article/testing-http-handlers-go/

Comment: You pass to the call of the `Excute` method of your template an anonymous instance of an anonymous struct which has a single field named Success. The parsed HTML form submitted by the client ends up in a variable named `details` _but it is never used._ A fun thing that the fact it's not used has been caught by the compiler which failed the compilation, and you evaded that by adding the `_ = details` statement.

Comment: How to solve this?

Comment: I'm afraid, you failed to grasp the main idea of how a `html/template` is executed, that is, how the template engine obtains values of those `.Field` references in the template. Once you grasp this, it will be obvious "how to solve". Please try reading more material on the templates first. I would also advise you to "start small": the problem with your approach is that it has too many moving parts: you have a web server, a web form and a handler in the web server which serves the form's "action"; that's just too much…

Comment: …To study how a template is rendered, it suffices to write a throw-away simple command-line app which renders a template to its standard output so you can just complite it, run it and immediately see the result. If the result is not OK, you try to modify the code, build, run and see. Repeat until you're satisfied with the result.

Answer (score 0):

following is a test implementation of given OP code.

I use a go1.15 usng GOPATH, set myself under `test/d/htt`.

I will only fix your handler, by adding the content variable to the template arguments, and its going to work.

```
$ touch main.go
$ touch handler.go
$ touch handler_test.go
$ mkdir -p ui/html
$ touch ui/html/about.html
$ touch ui/html/footer.html
$ touch ui/html/base.html
```

**main.go**

```
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func makeTemlate(base string) *template.Template {
    files := []string{base, "ui/html/footer.html", "ui/html/base.html"}
    return template.Must(template.ParseFiles(files...))
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/about", About)
    log.Println("Starting the server at :4000")
    http.ListenAndServe(":4000", nil)
}
```

**handler.go**

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
)

var aboutTmpl = makeTemlate("ui/html/about.html")

type Details struct {
    Success bool
    Content string
}

func About(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.Method != http.MethodPost {
        aboutTmpl.Execute(w, nil)
        return
    }
    details := Details{
        Success: true,
        Content: r.FormValue("content"),
    }
    aboutTmpl.Execute(w, details)
}
```

**handler_test.go**

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "net/url"
    "strings"
    "testing"
)

func TestAboutHandlerGetMethod(t *testing.T) {
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "/about", nil)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }

    rr := httptest.NewRecorder()
    handler := http.HandlerFunc(About)
    handler.ServeHTTP(rr, req)

    if status := rr.Code; status != http.StatusOK {
        t.Errorf("handler returned wrong status code: got %v want %v",
            status, http.StatusOK)
    }
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    io.Copy(&buf, rr.Body)
    b := buf.Bytes()
    if !bytes.Contains(b, []byte(`<form action="/about" method="POST" name="about" id="about">`)) {
        t.Errorf("form must be displayed when fetch with GET method, got=\n%s", b)
    }
}

func TestAboutHandlerPostMethod(t *testing.T) {
    form := url.Values{}
    form.Add("content", "Hellocontent")
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "/about", strings.NewReader(form.Encode()))
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
    req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

    rr := httptest.NewRecorder()
    handler := http.HandlerFunc(About)
    handler.ServeHTTP(rr, req)

    if status := rr.Code; status != http.StatusOK {
        t.Errorf("handler returned wrong status code: got %v want %v",
            status, http.StatusOK)
    }
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    io.Copy(&buf, rr.Body)
    b := buf.Bytes()
    if bytes.Contains(b, []byte(`<form action="/about" method="POST" name="about" id="about">`)) {
        t.Errorf("form must not be displayed when fetch with POST method, got=\n%s", b)
    }
    if !bytes.Contains(b, []byte(`Hellocontent`)) {
        t.Errorf("output must include the dispay of the posted content, got=\n%s", b)
    }
}
```

**ui/html/base.html**

```
{{define "base"}}
    {{template "title" .}}
    {{template "body" .}}
{{end}}
```

**ui/html/about.html**

```
{{template "base" .}}
{{define "title"}} About {{end}}
{{define "body"}}
    {{if .Success}}
        {{.Content}}
    {{else}}
        <h1>About</h1>
        <form action="/about" method="POST" name="about" id="about">
            <div>
                <label>Content</label>
                <textarea name="content"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </div>
        </form>
    {{end}}
{{end}}
```

**ui/html/footer.html**

```
// left empty...
```

Finally, i run `go test -v .`

```
=== RUN   TestAboutHandlerGetMethod
--- PASS: TestAboutHandlerGetMethod (0.00s)
=== RUN   TestAboutHandlerPostMethod
--- PASS: TestAboutHandlerPostMethod (0.00s)
PASS
ok      test/d/htt  0.005s
```

Final notes, the http post test can be written using `http.PostForm`, for simplification and dryness, https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#PostForm